# Is the universal state always a pure state?

Tags: quantum-information

If I have $n$ quantum systems and nothing else, can I always write the joint state of all the $n$ quantum systems as a pure state? I know that the $n$ systems have no correlations with any external system. However, is there a possibility that their joint state can only be written as a mixed state and not as a pure state. If it can be either, can  you please tell me under what conditions is it a pure or mixed state?

Comment: If there is nothing this system can be considered a subsystem of, i.e. no chance for it to be entangled with another system, then how would a mixed state arise? Clearly only if your initial conditions already were a mixed state. Whether your initial conditions allow for that or not is not an objectively answerable question, but depends on what you are trying to model.

Comment: Based on your first sentence, there's a possibility my understanding of a mixed state is lacking. Say I have 1- qubit state and nothing else. Can I not write down a state of the form $\psi = 0.5(|0\rangle\langle0| + |1\rangle\langle1|)$? I'm not sure what the physical implications of this are though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purification_of_quantum_state

Comment: @CountIblis I have an idea of purifications. Can you please tell me how this applies here. Even if the world state is a mixed state, you don't have an additional Hilbert space (which I think needs to be at least as big as the world state's) to purify the world state.

Comment: @IanDsouza This is really a question how you define the basic axioms of quantum mechanics - you can either demand the overall system has to be pure, or you can allow for mixed states.  Either is fine.  Note that talking about the state of the whole universe is somewhat subtle - QM is about predicting outcomes of observations, and in that case there is no observer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to consider how one would prepare a mixed state. We prepare a pure state $ |\psi_i >$ with probability $p_i$ and then forget what pure state we had. It is this forgetting process that makes it impossible to have a system with both a pure state representation and a mixed state representation. This is because whether or not it is either depends on what amount of knowledge we have. If we have everything about the system then we have a pure state. But if we lose information then we do not know everything about our system and so we use a mixed state. This is why mixed state are used to describe closed systems interacting with the environment. The environment is by definition something we do not have control over and takes with it information after it entangles with our system.